# Disk full and the system freezes after entering password at the login screen

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu, disk-management

My entire Kubuntu partition is full for some reason. Everything has become extremely slow. I'm not even able to run terminal. The last thing I remember doing was installing Python 3.

The computer is dual boot with windows 11. I have tried many ways to delete files and make space in the Kubuntu partition so I can log into it, but no luck.

On Windows 11, I've tried mounting the Kubuntu partition using Ext2read and Linux Reader, but none of them work.

I've also tried to use a Ubuntu Live CD to get into the partition, but I couldn't make any changes to the files.

The clean command in the recovery mode didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
zedd@zedd-kubuntu:/var/log$ sudo du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G"
[sudo] password for zedd: 
2.8G    /opt
16M     /root
25M     /etc
589M    /boot
7.3G    /snap
65G     /home
64G     /var
du: cannot access '/proc/13221/task/13221/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/13221/task/13221/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/13221/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/13221/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/doc': Permission denied
3.3M    /run
13G     /usr
152G    /
152G    total
```

Then I used `ls -alh` to identify large files in /var/log:

```
zedd@zedd-kubuntu:/var/log$ ls -alh
total 53G
drwxrwxr-x  17 root   syslog          4.0K Jun 25 00:00 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 root   root            4.0K Jun 16 21:52 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             36K Jun 23 03:00 alternatives.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             15K Jun  2 21:44 alternatives.log.1
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             298 Sep  6  2020 alternatives.log.10.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             127 Jul 18  2020 alternatives.log.11.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             194 Jul 18  2020 alternatives.log.12.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             455 Feb 21 10:55 alternatives.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             175 Sep 13  2021 alternatives.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root            5.4K Aug 31  2021 alternatives.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             692 Aug 29  2021 alternatives.log.5.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             126 Mar 22  2021 alternatives.log.6.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             851 Mar  6  2021 alternatives.log.7.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             133 Feb 22  2021 alternatives.log.8.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             231 Oct  3  2020 alternatives.log.9.gz
drwxr-x---   2 root   adm             4.0K Jun 23 02:28 apache2
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm                0 Jun 25 00:00 apport.log
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm              621 Jun 24 11:12 apport.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm              869 Jun 22 05:28 apport.log.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm             3.4K Jun 17 21:15 apport.log.3.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm              419 Jun 14 18:46 apport.log.4.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm              587 Jun 13 14:23 apport.log.5.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm              577 Jun 11 04:11 apport.log.6.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm             7.3K Jun 10 20:39 apport.log.7.gz
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root            4.0K Jun 24 11:12 apt
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm              56K Jun 25 00:17 auth.log
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm             116K Jun 17 22:04 auth.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm             7.2K Jun 13 07:44 auth.log.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm              11K Jun  6 09:35 auth.log.3.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm              788 May 29 19:33 auth.log.4.gz
-rw-------   1 root   root               0 Jun 25 00:00 boot.log
-rw-------   1 root   root             16K Jun 25 00:00 boot.log.1
-rw-------   1 root   root             50K Jun 24 09:32 boot.log.2
-rw-------   1 root   root            7.5K Jun 22 05:02 boot.log.3
-rw-------   1 root   root            7.3K Jun 21 21:55 boot.log.4
-rw-------   1 root   root             23K Jun 20 16:51 boot.log.5
-rw-------   1 root   root             29K Jun 17 11:20 boot.log.6
-rw-------   1 root   root            8.0K Jun 16 00:00 boot.log.7
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             56K Aug  5  2019 bootstrap.log
-rw-rw----   1 root   utmp             384 Jun 20 16:55 btmp
-rw-rw----   1 root   utmp             768 May 30 22:55 btmp.1
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root            4.0K Jun 25 00:00 cups
drwxr-xr-x   5 root   root            4.0K Jun  3 00:43 dist-upgrade
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm              86K Jun 24 21:07 dmesg
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm              89K Jun 24 11:13 dmesg.0
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm              22K Jun 24 09:32 dmesg.1.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm              22K Jun 23 03:46 dmesg.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm              22K Jun 23 03:15 dmesg.3.gz
-rw-r-----   1 root   adm              22K Jun 23 02:58 dmesg.4.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root            1.6M Jun 24 11:12 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root            1.9M Jun  3 00:19 dpkg.log.1
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root            3.2K Mar  6  2021 dpkg.log.10.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             17K Feb 22  2021 dpkg.log.11.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root            5.8K Oct  5  2020 dpkg.log.12.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             572 May 30 03:36 dpkg.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             695 Mar 28 15:54 dpkg.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             11K Feb 21 11:50 dpkg.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             233 Nov  2  2021 dpkg.log.5.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root            2.2K Sep 13  2021 dpkg.log.6.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root            336K Aug 31  2021 dpkg.log.7.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             15K Aug 29  2021 dpkg.log.8.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root            2.3K Mar 22  2021 dpkg.log.9.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             32K Aug 29  2021 faillog
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root            4.0K Mar  3  2020 firebird
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             16K Jun 23 03:02 fontconfig.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root            2.4K Jun 24 21:07 gpu-manager.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root            2.4K Jun 24 11:28 gpu-manager-switch.log
drwxrwxr-x   3 root   root            4.0K Dec 29  2019 installer
drwxr-sr-x+  3 root   systemd-journal 4.0K Dec 29  2019 journal
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm             2.3M Jun 25 00:21 kern.log
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm              27G Jun 17 21:59 kern.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm             261K Jun 13 07:44 kern.log.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm             524K Jun  6 09:35 kern.log.3.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm              22K May 29 19:33 kern.log.4.gz
-rw-rw-r--   1 root   utmp            286K Aug 29  2021 lastlog
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm                0 Sep 13  2021 mail.log
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm              971 Aug 29  2021 mail.log.1
drwxr-xr-x   2 mpd    audio           4.0K Jun  6 09:35 mpd
drwxr--r--   2 root   nordvpn         4.0K Jan 23  2020 nordvpn
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root              20 Jun 24 21:07 prime-supported.log
drwx------   2 root   root            4.0K Aug 29  2021 private
drwxr-x---   3 root   adm             4.0K Jun 20 16:51 samba
-rw-r--r--   1 sddm   sddm               0 Aug 29  2021 sddm.log
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm             1.1M Jun 25 00:21 syslog
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm              27G Jun 17 22:04 syslog.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm             647K Jun 13 07:44 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm             1.3M Jun  6 09:35 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm              52K May 29 19:33 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm             142K Mar 22  2021 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog adm              39K Mar 11  2021 syslog.7.gz
-rw-------   1 root   root             63K Aug 29  2021 tallylog
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             685 Jun  3 00:43 ubuntu-advantage.log
-rw-------   1 root   root             685 Jun  2 21:26 ubuntu-advantage.log.1
-rw-------   1 root   root             210 Feb 21 10:52 ubuntu-advantage.log.2.gz
-rw-------   1 root   root             406 Jan 21 03:30 ubuntu-advantage.log.3.gz
-rw-------   1 root   root             175 Jan 11 15:17 ubuntu-advantage.log.4.gz
-rw-------   1 root   root             178 Nov  3  2021 ubuntu-advantage.log.5.gz
-rw-------   1 root   root             192 Sep 13  2021 ubuntu-advantage.log.6.gz
-rw-------   1 root   root            3.0K Jun 24 21:54 ubuntu-advantage-timer.log
-rw-------   1 root   root             314 May 30 23:22 ubuntu-advantage-timer.log.1
-rw-------   1 root   root             110 Apr 20 18:03 ubuntu-advantage-timer.log.2.gz
-rw-------   1 root   root             137 Mar 28 15:53 ubuntu-advantage-timer.log.3.gz
drwxr-x---   2 root   adm             4.0K Jun  4 01:28 unattended-upgrades
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root            4.0K Aug 29  2021 upgrade
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root            4.0K Jun 24 21:07 vmware
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             43K Jun 11 04:08 vmware-installer
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             73K Jun 23 02:58 vnetlib
drwxrwxrwx   2 root   root            4.0K Dec 30  2019 wpslog
-rw-rw-r--   1 root   utmp            295K Jun 25 00:15 wtmp
-rw-rw-r--   1 root   utmp            6.0K Aug 29  2021 wtmp.1
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             55K Jun 24 23:21 Xorg.0.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root             43K Jun 24 11:28 Xorg.0.log.old
```

The largest files are `syslog.1`and`kern.log.1`. Each takes 27GB of space. Dealing with the unusually large log files fixed the problem for me. Thank you for the help. @guiverc

Comment: It might help if you're specific as to "*last thing I remember doing was installing Python 3*" as it's already installed; if you change the default python3 version you can have problems with desktop/GUI logins; though terminal logins will still work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am not a Linux pro, not sure if it would help but I was installing Python using terminal by copying and pasting the commands on their website. Then I left the computer for around 1 hour, but I found the installation was still in process when I got back and the entire system was frozen. I was not able to do anything not even click the reboot button. So the only thing I could do was to press the power button, forcing it to restart. Then I found that system would freeze after entering the password on the login screen.

Comment: As `python3` is already installed (*as many `apt` like commands use python3 in operation; you'll have had python3 installed before hand otherwise you'd get errors*) but you can safely tell the Linux kernel to reboot & avoid damage by power-off buttons.. If you can't remember the commands search "magic sysrq" using a phone etc & you'll find how to on wikipedia & other sites - it's a linux command so works with any GNU/Linux with real keyboard (so not android phones!).  I'd boot to a *live* system and perform file-system checks (eg. `fsck`) then I'd hope the system would boot.

Comment: Kubuntu 22.04 LTS comes with python 3.10 by default (ie. `python3 | 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 | jammy          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`) so you should provide details of what you attempted to install/change as effects of changing a default python3 can be problematic.  Another possibility (*if not damage caused by your changing default python3*) is hardware problems & co-incidence, ie. check system health (*drives* using SMART (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools), PSU, RAM etc) but python3 change you've mentioned.

Comment: have you fully shut down windows?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. I have managed to log into the system successfully by choosing the root option under the advanced option for Ubuntu on the grub2 page. Therefore I could use commands to make space from the disk and log into the system. However, I discovered that the reason why the system was not responsive while installing python is that Python had generated some large log files which took up all the remaining space in the disk. The size of /var/log has reached 56.6GB. Do you know how to deal with these files?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I have managed to log into the system successfully by choosing the `root` option under the `Advanced option for Ubuntu` on the Grub2 page. Therefore I could use commands to make space from the disk and log into the system.

After that, I used `sudo du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G"` to locate the what folder was eating up space, it was `/var/log`.